# Linked list with multiple structs

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I am new to linked list and I had no problem using one struct with linked list. However, when I tried to create nodes using struct "people" and link them together using the other struct "Queue", I got a segmentation fault. Could someone please take a look at what is wrong in my code with double structs?

```
enum Name{Ashley, Peter, Mike, Bill, Chris, Kate, Marry};

struct people{
    Name name;
    double height;
    int weight;
};
struct Queue{
    people* ppl;
    int data;
    Queue* next;
};

void print(Queue * queueHead){
    Queue * traverse = queueHead;
    while(traverse!=NULL){
        cout << "height " << traverse->ppl->height << endl;
        traverse = traverse->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    Queue * queueHead = NULL;

    people * node = new people;
    node->name = Ashley;
    node->height = 5.5;
    node->weight = 125;
    queueHead->ppl = node;
    queueHead->next = NULL;
    node=NULL;

    print(queueHead);

}
```

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer is like the archetype of segmentation faults.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without first allocating memory for queueHead (which is NULL in your case):

```
queueHead->ppl = node;
queueHead->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Oh yes thank you. I thought declaring it to NULL would work as allocating the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The access to `queueHead->ppl` causes the `seg fault`. The problem is that `queueHead` is a pointer and needs to point to a valid memory location.

Thus try:

```
Queue *queueHead = new Queue;
```

Also, consider using a smart pointer class e.g. `std::unique_ptr` for managing pointers/memory. You already forgot `delete` in your program(hope that this convinced you).

Comment: Thank you I got that. Is that necessary to delete the pointer if I have already set node = NULL ?

Comment: @FannyZhang Yes you need to pair every `new` and `delete`